# Prove that $5\cos A+3\cos\left(A+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+3$ lies between $-4$ and $10$

Tags: trigonometry

After much of solving, I arrive at the expression
$$\frac{1}{2}\left[13 \cos A-3\sqrt{3}\sin A +6\right].$$

I can't conclude anything from this.
Please help. Hints are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2}\left[13 \cos A-3\sqrt{3}\sin A +6\right]$

with $ \left| 13\cos A-3\sqrt{3}\sin A\right| \leq \sqrt{196} = 14 $

u get to:

$\frac{1}{2}\left[13 \cos A-3\sqrt{3}\sin A +6\right] \leq \frac{1}{2}\left[14 +6\right] = 10$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$ \left| 13\cos A-3\sqrt{3}\sin A\right| \leq \sqrt{13^2+27} = 14. $$